# How to obtain graph url

Tags: facebook

How to obtain graph root url `https://graph.facebook.com/` using FB JS SDK or should I hardcode it everywhere?

Comment: @genesis: I need to get user's picture url, which is `https://graph.facebook.com/<uid>/picture`

Comment: so what's problem? http://graph.facebook.com/ladygaga/picture

Comment: @genesis: the problem is that I need to hardcode it

Comment: Uhm, why -1? Is the question that bad?!

Comment: I've got no idea, I haven't downvote it. But I still don't know what does "hardcore" mean

Comment: @genesis: compare `src: FB._domain.graph + FB._userID + '/picture'` and `src: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + FB._userID + '/picture'`. In the second case I hardcoded the domain, in the first case used the one that FB JS SDK knows about. If something will be changed - first code need not to be rewritten.

Comment: @genesis: btw http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the property I was looking for: [FB._domain.graph](https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/src/core/prelude.js#L86)